# Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "530", with message "530 SMTP authentication is required."

Tags: symfony, mailer

```
###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

this is a part from my .env 
 i'm trying to send an email once the user is registred 
 but i dont know wht to put in MAILER DSN, and i am getting this error 
[THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs9Ld.png)
and last but not least here's my mailer service

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;

class Mailer{

    /**
     * @var MailerInterface
     */
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function sendMail($email, $token){
        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from('Lost-found@foundonly.com')
            ->to(new Address($email))
            ->subject('Thanks for signing up! Just one more thing to do')

            // path of the Twig template to render
            ->htmlTemplate('emails/signup.html.twig')

            // pass variables (name => value) to the template
            ->context([
                'token' => $token,
            ])
        ;

        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }
}
```

and finally  the register controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegisterType;
use App\Service\Mailer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;


class RegisterController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;


    /**
     * @var Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/signup", name="signup")
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function register(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class,$user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted()&&$form->isValid()){
            $user->setPassword(
                $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user,$form->get("password")->getData())
            );
            $user->setToken($this->generateToken());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $this->mailer->sendMail($user->getEmail(),$user->getToken());
            $this->addFlash("success", "you are more than welcome into our community, just one more step | Check your mail please");
        }//37.12

        return $this->render('register/register.html.twig',[
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function generateToken(): string
    {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(32)),'+/','-_'),'=');
    }
}

?>
```

so please can anyone help me here? i really dont know wht to put in the mailer_dsn

Comment: now i'm getting this new error : Connection could not be established with host "localhost:25": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to localhost:25 (Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée)

Comment: If you don't have SMTP server and you want to make some test in local environment, you should replace this `MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost` in dot env file by `MAILER_DSN=null://localhost`.

Comment: i'm send the mail to a temporary email generated for this site
her's the link [https://temp-mail.org/fr/] but i never received the mail

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly configure your Mailer transport. It can either be an SMTP server or local sendmail binary.

If you don't want to bother with sendmail and prefer using SMTP transport, the easiest solution would be using gmail smtp server with [symfony/google-mailer](https://github.com/symfony/google-mailer) component

More info:
**[Sending Emails with Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html)**